# How can I use LEFT and REPLACE on the same column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, syntax

I want to select a column and remove(replace with space) any line feeds or carriage returns and I want to get only the first 40 characters in the column after the replace.

Here is the query I tried but I get

```
select date, REPLACE(LEFT(message, '\r', ' '), 30)
from table1 
where message like 'testing%'
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' '), 30) from events_cleared where message like 'testing%' ' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the ordering of your arguments incorrect (you have passed the `REPLACE` arguments to `LEFT`). Try this:

```
select date, REPLACE(LEFT(message, 30), '\r', ' ')
from table1 
where message like 'testing%'
```

Comment: Your solution worked, less on parenthesis at the end. select date, REPLACE(LEFT(message, 30), '\r', ' ')
from table1 
where message like 'testing%'  THANK YOU ALL!

Comment: @MikePatterson sorry about that, bad cut & paste... I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

Replace needs the arguments '\r; and ' '

```
LEFT(REPLACE(message, '\r', ' '), 30)
```

or

```
REPLACE(LEFT(message,30), '\r', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function identifiers are switched and therefore the number of arguments weren't right. if you want `replace()` to happen first is has to go deeper in the nesting than the `left()`. You also wrote `30` as second argument to `left()` which would give you only 30 characters, not 40.

```
SELECT date,
       left(replace(message, '\r', ' '), 40)
       FROM table1
       WHERE message LIKE 'testing%';
```